# Redirect in web.config

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewriting

Can someone please let me know why the following will not rewrite correctly?

```
<rule name="Redirect account listing with levelId" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^account/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)[?levelId=]$" />
<conditions>
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="account/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

I'm trying to redirect so that the "?levelId=  is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...

```
<rule name="Redirect account listing with levelId b" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^account/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)" />
<conditions>
  <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
  <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^levelID=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="account/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
```